# Wordpress: How to find string in sql column if other column has specific value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

NB: SQL NOOB.

I'm looking for all instances of a string in my wp_posts table > post_content column using this query:

```
SELECT LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'string I want to query','')) AS occurs FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%string I want to query%'
```

This works great, but I want to limit the query to only return occurrences that have a value of `type` in a different column: `post_type`.

This is what I came up with, but it's not working:

```
SELECT LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'string I want to query','')) Where post_type = 'type' AS occurs FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%string I want to query%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for anyone else looking. Just need to add an `AND` to the `WHERE` section of the query:

```
SELECT LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'string I want to query','')) AS occurs FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%string I want to query%' AND post_type = 'type'
```